# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http

I have different issues with this exception, Please try to understand.

- I'm sending data from one application to another through web service call in Java.
- whenever I called it will connect to some other application. in that
  a situation I get the above exception, this problem occur only in
  byte Grid server.
- We **solved above problem like this** our admin removed security,
  means we have http**s** they removed **s** so we are working with
  **HTTP**, but it's not good, I want to connect through web service call with security, can any one give me the best idea.Please see my sample code

  ```
  byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  int postDataLength = postData.length;
  String request = PropertyFactory.getProperty("someUrl");
  url = new URL(request);
  postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  ```

  can I handle through code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Byte grid having internal firewall so its may be stop, Please contact with byte grid team.

Comment: thanx a lot, the firewall stopping request we contacted issue is solved

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Oracle JDK between 1.8.0_51 and 1.8.0_60, there was an issue when connecting via IP address instead of hostname. In the case of using the IP-address, this address also has to be mentioned in the Subject alternative names of the cert. According to [Mulesoft Support](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka434000000TPTVAA4/Error-No-subject-alternative-names-matching-IP-address-when-using-MongoDB-connector) a workaround would be to set the JVM argument "jdk.tls.trustNameService" to true - resulting in a reverse name lookup for the IP address.